# R nest_by() does put data in list() object

Tags: dplyr

When I try to put R nest_by() I'm expecting the data column to have the data elements in a list.

```
iris %>% 
  nest_by(Species)
```

However when I do it, i get the data output fully printed in the table.

[image]

Based on the documentation in the on the dplyr site, I see the below?
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest_by.html

[image]

To make it equal to the documentation I usually have to do

```
iris %>% 
  nest_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(data=list(data))
```

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how `View()` and Rmd / Quarto inline chunk output are rendered, try running your example outside of a Notebook or enable *Chunk output in Console* setting to get the desired output:

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  nest_by(Species)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Rowwise:  Species
#>   Species                  data
#>   <fct>      <list<tibble[,4]>>
#> 1 setosa               [50 × 4]
#> 2 versicolor           [50 × 4]
#> 3 virginica            [50 × 4]

iris %>% 
  nest_by(Species) %>% 
  glimpse()
#> Rows: 3
#> Columns: 2
#> Rowwise: Species
#> $ Species <fct> setosa, versicolor, virginica
#> $ data    <list<tibble[,4]>> [<tbl_df[50 x 4]>], [<tbl_df[50 x 4]>], [<tbl_df[50 x 4]>]…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Screenshots from inline output and Viewer:

- [Identical environment, *Chunk output* set to inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRNoy.png)
- [Viewer uses the same rendering approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcwYV.png)

Comment: oh thank you! is there any way to turn it off? it takes forever to load for large datasets when that happens.

Comment: Not sure. I usually prefer having chunk output in console, that covers most such cases.  But I'm not aware of any methods that would allow to control iniline output or selectively direct output from some chunks to console while keeping output from others inline. Perhaps appending  `glimpse() ` to such pipelines is some sort of a workaround -- glimpse silently passes on input so values are not affected, so it safe to leave those calls at the end of (or even in the middle) of pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the below

```r
iris %>% nest(.by=Species)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

````r
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species    data             
  <fct>      <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>

```
````

Comment: I'm familiar with this - but this `nest_by()` is similiar but different than `nest()` int hat it creates a `rowwise()` object.